# Как можно вывести сумму многомерного объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть объект cartData и функция setItemTotal. Все работает. Но, теперь не могу додумать, как сделать функцию getObjTotal, чтобы она возвращала сумму setItemTotal объектов внутри главного объекта.

```
 
    var cartData = {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "/public/assets/media/uploads/products/Инсталляция под унитаз/Installyaciya.jpg",
        "title": "Инсталляция под унитаз",
        "slug": "installyaciya-pod-unitaz",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": "2043.00"        
      },
      "5": {
        "id": 5,
        "image": "/public/assets/media/uploads/products/Title/Title.jpg",
        "title": "Title",
        "slug": "title",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": "1144.00"        
      }
    }

function setItemTotal(obj) {
   itemTotal = 0;
   for(let item in obj) {
        let price = clearPrice(obj[item]['price']);        
        let quantity = Number(obj[item]['quantity']);
        itemTotal = price*quantity;        
   } 
   return number_format(itemTotal/100, 2, ',', '');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const cartData = {
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "image": "/public/assets/media/uploads/products/Инсталляция под унитаз/Installyaciya.jpg",
    "title": "Инсталляция под унитаз",
    "slug": "installyaciya-pod-unitaz",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "2043.00"
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 5,
    "image": "/public/assets/media/uploads/products/Title/Title.jpg",
    "title": "Title",
    "slug": "title",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": "1144.00"
  }
};

const getObjTotal = cars => {
  let total = 0;

  //for (const [, car] of Object.entries(cars)) total += car.quantity * car.price;
  for (const {quantity,price} of Object.values(cars)) total += quantity * price;

  return total;
};

//const getObjTotal = cars => Object.values(cars).reduce((total, car) => total + car.price * car.quantity,0);

console.log(getObjTotal(cartData));
```

Comment: Можно чуть упростить: `for (const { quantity, price } of Object.values(cars)) total += quantity * price;`

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Добавил в ответ.